# Android Signed Apk crashed in below 5.0 Versions

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, apk

I create a signed APK and upload that, it crashes in all below version of marshmallow. The signed APK works on Android above version 5.0, but not on <5.0. The AppCompat Library is linked with the project in Android.

And when I normally run the same project in android 5.0 it work perfectly but signed apk not run in 5.0.

And it was also not generating the crash report.

In the AndroidManifest.xml I have declared:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ahgp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/assets/fonts'] } }
```

}

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
        }
    }
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3') {
        exclude group: 'io.card'
    }
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.3.jar')
    // compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'org.glassfish.main:javax.annotation:4.0-b33'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:(4,5)'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
/* compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10+'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10+'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10+'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10+'*/
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.3.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

//noinspection GradleCompatible


 /*  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'*/
// glide
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

// acra crash report
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Any logcat error?

Comment: no even it's not generating the crash report.

Comment: please implement crashlytics in your project :)

Comment: also post full gradle file here, have implemented facebook ?

Comment: I've already implement the crashlytics but it's not generating the crash report when it was crashed on splash start

Comment: yupp.. i added facebook, twiter and quickBlox login in my app. and i added my full gradle file please see my updated question

Comment: Can you reproduce the crash locally? e.g. on an emulator. If so, please provide the stacktrace or errors from the logcat. Also, how do you sign your APK? Do you run a command manually (if so, which one?) or do you let Studio do it?

Answer (score 0):

In your build gradle file minimum os is 21 so your app will not supported below to 21.

Comment: But when i run directly in the same phone it's work fine

Comment: Please check your device which OS actually in it. It's not possible bro. :)

Comment: @Sameer ji. Normal apk will run fine without any issue but when i run the signed apk in the same phone it will crash it. phone android version is lollipop 5.0

Comment: then you might asking the wrong question, as @SameerJani you cant run it on versions under 21